# How to link 2 Fragments with both having listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I need your help.. I have been working around for 2 days and is still confused with fragments..

My aim here is to create a fragment that contains a listview. On each item clicked, it will display another fragment with another listview (like a submenu but displayed in a different fragment).

I have here the code for my Fragment

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView masterlist;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.master_fragment, container, false);
    masterlist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.masterlistview);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.masterlist, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    masterlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    masterlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    long position = masterlist.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
    if(position == 0){
        System.out.println("Item 0");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Item 1");
    }
}
```

In my onItemClick, how can i call a fragment.? i have 2 fragments with listviews but has different array in them. like if position == 0, call FragmentA. else, call FragmentB.

I have created an Interface in my MasterFragment

```
public interface Communicator {
    void respond(int index);
}
```

Then implemented it in my MainActivity.. but I am not really sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create callback interface. implement this interface in activity from where fragment called. onclick of item in fragment send position with callback method. Then call your fragment with respect to position

your fragment should look like this

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

public inteface OnItemClickResponse

{
    void itemClick ( int position);
}

OnItemClickResponse itemClickResponse;

ListView masterlist;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.master_fragment, container, false);
    masterlist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.masterlistview);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.masterlist, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    masterlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    masterlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    itemClickResponse = (OnItemClickResponse) getActivity();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    long position = masterlist.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
    if (position == 0) {
        itemClickResponse.itemClick(position);
        System.out.println("Item 0");
    } else {
        itemClickResponse.itemClick(position);
        System.out.println("Item 1");
    }
}
```

and in activity(must implement interface 'OnItemClickResponse')

```
@Override
public void itemClick(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        Fragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    } else {
        Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have created an interface Communicator in my fragment.. please see my edit

Comment: where is this getSupportFragmentManager() came from.. it says cannot resolve.

Comment: use getFragmentManager or extend your activity with AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

```
if(position == 0){
 Fragment newFragment = new FragmemtA();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();      
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
 }
else
{
 Fragment newFragment = new FragmemtB();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();  
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
 }
```